# Ambiguous redirect error with echo

Tags: bash, echo

Trying to write simple stuff to all text files in a specific directory .

```
$ touch a{1..9}.txt
$ echo "." > *.txt
bash: *.txt: ambiguous redirect
```

I don't know why this error occurs , I mean the basic principle that it stands on ..
I tried quoting the asterisk , but it creates a file that its name is "*.txt" .
Is there anyway to do this without looping ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to `touch` if you are going to overwrite the files immediately anyway.

```
echo "." | tee a{1..9}.txt >/dev/null
```

If you want to overwrite all existing files matching a specific wildcard expression, you can use that as the argument to `tee`, of course:

```
echo "." | tee *.txt >/dev/null
```

You generally cannot redirect to a wildcard expression unless you are sure that it expands to exactly one existing file.

Comment: `tee` also prints to standard output and you want to avoid that.  `echo` obviously *does* produce some output and `tee` will copy that to the destination files *as well as* reproducing it on stdout.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `tee` command.

```
echo "." | tee a{1..9}.txt
```